# Как из метода в сервисе вывести результирующую переменную в thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Мой метод в сервисе, переменная, которую нужно передать во view, - `result`:

```
@Override
public int sum(String line) {    
String content = new String(line.getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    List<String> word = Arrays.asList(content.split(" "));
    int[] numbers = word.stream()
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();   
    int result = Arrays.stream(numbers).sum();
    return result;}
```

Мой контроллер

```
@PostMapping("/sum")
public String sum(String line, Model model) {   
 operationsService.sum(line);
 model.addAttribute("condition",Boolean.TRUE);    return "main";
```

Comment: Присвойте возвращаемое значение какой-нибудь переменной и добавляйте её в модель. Или можете сразу добавлять результат вызова функции.

Comment: Проблема в том, что у меня метод находится в сервисе, а модель в контроллере, я не могу результирующую переменную вытащить из метода, а просто передать функцию я шаблонизатор я тоже вроде как не могу

Comment: "Метод находится в сервисе" - так ведь вся работа контроллера состоит в том, что он обращается к сервису и результатами из него пичкает представление. Внедрите этот сервис в ваш контроллер, вызывайте какие угодно его методы и пользуйтесь результатами.

Comment: @Byb естественно я инжектнул сервис в контроллер и вызвал там нужный мне метод, но смысл вопроса в том, что я не понимаю как в thymeleaf передать результат этого метода, я могу сразу в методе model.addAttribute передать имя и в значение передать функцию, но тогда у меня ничего не выводит в tmlf

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как передать метод для получения его результата в шаблон Thymeleaf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1546784/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd-thymeleaf)

Comment: @RomanC, получилось наоборот :)  автор повторил свой вопрос через три часа, и получил [**аналогичный** ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1546802/386633), но сделал это с дублированного аккаунта.

Comment: @NowhereMan Зачем он повторил? Наверно этот вопрос будет удален. Я не могу его закрыть как дубликат потому, что на него есть ответ.

Answer (score 0):

По идее достаточно установить соответствующий атрибут в модели, чтобы он стал доступен как переменная:

```java
// метод контроллера
@PostMapping("/sum")
public String sum(String line, Model model) {       
    model.addAttribute("mySum", operationsService.sum(line));
    model.addAttribute("condition", Boolean.TRUE);
    return "main";
}
```

Затем переменная `mySum` станет доступна в соответствующем Thymeleaf шаблоне `main.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head></head>
<body>
<!-- ... -->
<p th:text="${mySum}"></p>
<!-- ... -->
</body>
</html>
```

К тому же в методе `sum` для чего-то создаётся слишком много промежуточных переменных, и его можно улучшить:

```java
// метод сервиса
@Override
public int sum(String line) {
    return Arrays.stream(new String(line.getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).split(" "))
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .sum();
}
```

Comment: Да, я все так и сделал, но очень плохо понимаю как вызывать переменую в thymeleaf, по примерам это делается так th:text="'result ' + ${operationsService.sum(line)}"
Но это не работает, или я что то не правильно делаю с передачей в шаблонизатор?
Насчет лишних переменных, это был быстрый брут форс, я больше был озадачен другой проблемой, но все равно спасибо за замечание)

Comment: @SergeyAvdeev, а где и как вы определили переменную `operationService`, что пытаетесь обратиться к ней в шаблоне?  Я дополнил ответ примером, как следует вывести содержимое переменной `mySum` в примерном шаблоне.