# Как вызвать метод из шаблона Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, mvc, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, el

У меня есть метод в сервисе

```
@Override
    public int sum(String line) {
        return Arrays.stream(new String(line.getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).split(" "))
                .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                .sum();
    }
```

Контроллер

```
@PostMapping("/sum")
    public String sum(@RequestParam String line, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("condition",Boolean.TRUE);
        model.addAttribute("result",operationsService.sum(line));// я так понял проблема где-то тут, из-за этого выдает ошибку
        return "main";
    }
```

И шаблон в thymeleaf

```
<form th:action="@{/sum}" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="line"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    <div th:if="${condition}">
        <p th:text="'result' + ${operationsService.sum(line)}"></p>
    </div>
</form>
```

При передачи строки(числа) в форму и отправке запроса, мне выдает такую ошибку

> EL1011E: Method call: Attempted to call method sum(null) on null context object

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка. Я так понял, я не правильно что-то прописываю в шаблонизаторе.

Comment: не нужно плодить аккаунты и задавать [одинаковые вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1546748/), см. [Я случайно создал две учётные записи, как их объединить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Шо за метка [el]? Снести ее надо бы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы же ведь буквально одной строчкой выше в представлении совершенно правильно обращаетесь к переменной `condition`, которую именно с таким названием поместили в модель строкой

```
model.addAttribute("condition",Boolean.TRUE);
```

Почему вы точно так же не хотите обращаться к переменной с именем `result`? Вот здесь

```
model.addAttribute("result",operationsService.sum(line));
```

вы кладёте результат работы функции `sum()` в модель, назначая передаваемой переменной имя `result`. Соответственно, по этому имени в представлении к этой переменной и обращайтесь:

```
...
<p th:text="'result' + ${result}"></p>
...
```

Разумеется, вызывать функции в представлении тоже можно. Например, вы могли бы передать в представление `operationsService` и `line`, и тогда такая запись, как у вас, вполне сработала бы.

Другое дело, что в данном случае это не нужно, так как вполне естественно выглядит вызов метода сервиса в контроллере и передача единственного результата `result` в модель.

Comment: спасибо большое, я так тоже пытался, но у меня вылазила ошибка, которая была обусловленна совсем в другом месте, после того как прочитал, понял что я не был совсем невнимательным)